# Is there a decltype equivalent in Swift?

Tags: c++, swift, c++11

In C++11 and latter, it is possible to use a compile time function like syntax named `decltype()` to reuse declaration type of a variable to declare another one without rewriting the type signature. Is there any equivalent syntactic tool in Swift?

*C++ Example:*

```
class SomeClass {
public: 
    SomeVeryLongTypeName* my_prop;
}

void foo() {
    SomeClass my_var = SomeClass();

    // Below code is a variable declaration, not a function call
    declytype(my_var.my_prop) some_prop = nullptr;

    // Below is same as above
    SomeVeryLongTypeName* some_prop = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, no direct equivalent syntactic tool readily available in Swift.

For something slightly similar you could, however, make use of generics to gain access to (at compile time) a metatype (grammar: `metatype-type → type­.­Type`), whereafter you can use an initializer expression to construct an instance of the concrete type (of the metatype).

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

typealias SomeVeryLongTypeName = Int
extension SomeVeryLongTypeName : Initializable {}

class SomeClass {
    let my_prop : SomeVeryLongTypeName
    required init() { my_prop = 1 }
}

func declmetatype<T: Initializable>(_: T) -> T.Type {
    return T.self
}

func foo() {
    let my_var = SomeClass()
    let some_prop = declmetatype(my_var.my_prop).init()
    some_prop = my_var.my_prop + 1
}
```

In `foo()` above, `some_prop` is of type `SomeVeryLongTypeName` (which, here, is simply `Int`), which due to Swift's static typing is naturally known at compile time.

Note, however, that in Swift we cannot use this technique to only declare types, but must also instantiate them. Moreover, there's no concept of *"default initializers"* in Swift (as compared to default CTOR:s in C++), hence the need to constrain the generic typeholder in `declmetatype(...)` to a protocol of our own, where we provide a blueprint to some initializer we'd like to use in a "default sense" from the metatype.

We may visit [the Language Reference - Types - Metatypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) for additional details on metatypes, particularly:

> Use an initializer expression **to construct an instance of a type**
>   from that type’s metatype value. For class instances, the initializer
>   that’s called must be marked with the `required` keyword or the entire
>   class marked with the `final` keyword.

Where I've emphasized the available use of metatypes to construct *instances* of types (as shown above), which does not, however, cover using metatypes to only *declare* types.

Comment: I trust the effort, this seems to be the answer in my case. Thank you very much.

Comment: I must note for the curious future reader that `let some_prop = declmetatype(my_var.my_prop).init()`  this line is the key point on the issue.

Comment: @diegoperini happy to help. It might also be good to point out the difference between the generic `declmetatype(_:)` method above and simply making use of the natively available global [`type(of:)` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2831805-type); the latter used to see the dynamic type of a value. I've shown the key difference between these two [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/bf1e3a97e83858426dab811877f13016) (compile time vs runtime/dynamic type).